# How I can move Window of Form2 if I move the error message?

Tags: c#

I have an error message:

```
if (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count == 0) {
    MessageBox.Show("You have not selected any instrument");
    //Location = this.Form2_Load();
    return;
}
```

How I can make this to appear in Form2 windows, and if I move Window of Form2 to move the error message too?

Answer (score 0):

The `MessageBox` is yet another window, which is also *modal*, i.e. you cannot use the parent window at all while it's being displayed. Furthermore, you don't get an instance of the `MessageBox` window; it's just a static method displaying it and returning a result, blocking all the while.

So if you want to have it movable with the parent window, you have to implement that functionality yourself. Create your own MessageBox window that displays a message and has a parent window. You can listen to that parent window's location or size changes to reposition yourself.

But if you go that route, I ask you from a UX standpoint to not just replicate a MessageBox. That kind of error message is essentially a [monolog box](http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/monolog_boxes_and_transparent_messages/) and there are far better patterns for the user. Having a transparent message would even solve the problem of having to move around the message box to stay within the window if it's moved.

One option that I'd probably go for in your context would be to just put the error message inline near the control where you can select instruments and use a short animation or something similar to grab the user's attention and direct them to correcting their mistake.

Comment: but I can block a windows to not  be moved ?

Comment: If it's your own, you can do whatever you want. If not, things get tricky.